# How to send false if i remove from array?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this in html:

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
  <input type="checkbox"  ngControl="announcement" (change)="onChange($event,announcement.code)">
 <span>{{announcement.name}}</span>   
 </label>
```

In my ts file i have this onChange:

```
 onChange(event, announcement) {
         let index = this.checked.indexOf(announcement);

        if (event.target.checked) {
                if (index === -1) {
                    this.checked.push(
                        {
                            'code': announcement,
                            'indicator': true
                        }
                    );
            }
        } else {
            console.log('remove');
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.checked.push(
                     {
                            'code': announcement,
                            'indicator': false
                        }
                );
            }
        }
         console.log(this.checked);
    }
```

Right now when user check checkbox in array i push object with announcement and true, but i want when user uncheck it to send that announcement and false. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be simple to use something like:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="announcement.checked" (change)="announcement.checked = !announcement.checked" />
    <span>{{announcement.name}}</span>
</label>
```

The [plunker as reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/7pAP0d8eHIHlVLzWuRwV?p=preview)

Comment: and then what? How to handle that?

Comment: What do you plan to handle? The state of announcement (checked or not) is available.

Comment: Yes but i have checkbox in ngFor so what i want is when check or uncheck one of chekbox to add in array that with true or false depends if he check or uncheck

Comment: i want to send value and true(check)/false(uncheck)

Comment: I see your point, but if you have a list of elements, each element will store their state, either checked or not. Therefore, you can use this element afterwards to do further logic.

Comment: For instance to get an array of booleans: 
`const theArray = announcements.map( announcement => announcement.checked
);`

Comment: What do you mean by "added values in array", can you give a look on the example I sent you? Put it a method then you can get the state you are looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144922/discussion-between-none-and-custodio).